# Acquire a SAML token in MSAL.js

Tags: jwt, saml, msal.js

I can acquire a JWT token using the SPA JavaScript Microsoft Authentication Library using acquireTokenSilent.

Instead of getting a signed JWT token, is there a way I can get a signed XML SAML token?

I have a backend application (out of my control to change) which is setup to receive SAML and will read the tokens and check them against a certificate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSAL is a client side library that supports OAuth and OpenID Connect and it is not designed for handling SAML.

Also ,[Single Sign-On SAML protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-on-saml-protocol) and [Federated Authentication with a SAML Identity Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-saml-idp) should be good starting points to implement SAML directly.