# As of today (August 2023) is SAML protocol supported by MSAL.js?

Tags: saml-2.0, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I'm working on a project where a client of ours would like to use their Azure account for SSO (now called Entra Verified ID it looks like) to log into our website (React [FE], Node [BE]).

My questions are...

- This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63510163/8378893) and this [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1074499/is-it-possible-to-use-msal-access-token-in-saml-fl) say SAML is NOT supported by MSAL. I'm not finding any recent information that refutes this. Is SAML still not supported by MSAL?
- Since our authentication happens on the BE I should use the NPM package, [Microsoft Authentication Library for Node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-node), correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, SAML is not supported by MSAL and never has been.

It's OIDC only.

If you need a client-side SAML stack, look [here](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43).